# Using two time values in while loop. The while loop doesn't stop when condition no longer 1. C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

My while loop isn't stopping even though one of the values becomes 'greater than' and the condition changes from `1` to `0`.

Before the while loops starts I set the time now in milliseconds. `milliseconds_now`
I also set a time five seconds in the future. `milliseconds_then`

I have `(milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then)` in the while loop. It should only be `1` for five seconds. I also print out `(milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then)` within the loop and it goes from printing '1' to printing '0' after five seconds.

I expect the loop to stop after five seconds. Instead it continues.

This is what I have in the terminal when I run the program at five seconds. It just keeps looping.

```
1644097691885 1644097692070
1
1644097691935 1644097692070
1
1644097691986 1644097692070
1
1644097692036 1644097692070
1
1644097692086 1644097692070
0
1644097692136 1644097692070
0
1644097692186 1644097692070
0
1644097692236 1644097692070
0
1644097692287 1644097692070
0
1644097692337 1644097692070
0
1644097692387 1644097692070
0
1644097692437 1644097692070
```

The code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto milliseconds_now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

auto milliseconds_then = milliseconds_now + 5000;
    
int main() {
    while (milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then) {

        auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto milliseconds_now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

        cout << milliseconds_now << " " << milliseconds_then << "\n";
        cout << (milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then) << "\n";

        usleep(50000);
    };
};
```

Comment: You may compile with flag `-Wshadow`  or -`Werror=shadow` , to make the compiler tells you about situations when you hide some variable with a new declaration inside chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the milliseconds_now inside the loop is not the same milliseconds_now being tested in the while loop. Change it to

```
while (milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then) {

    auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    milliseconds_now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

    cout << milliseconds_now << " " << milliseconds_then << "\n";
    cout << (milliseconds_now < milliseconds_then) << "\n";

    usleep(50000);
};
```

why? you are declaring a new variable inside the loop, often the compiler will warn you about it.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I wonder why `auto` makes it a different variable than the one with the same name in the while loop. I would not have thought two variables with same name were possible.

Comment: its nothing to do with auto.  works the same if you had int or time_t or whatever. Read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing